# Use of PCRE regular expressions with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, pcre

Is there a way to enable and use full-featured PCRE regular expressions reliably with a MySQL database on a production server, i.e. with capture groups, pattern modifiers (case-sensitive/insensitive, multiline), meta-characters, escape sequences (`\s`, `\w`) and other PCRE goodies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/)

> lib_mysqludf_preg is a library of mysql UDFs (user-defined-functions)
>   that provide access to the PCRE (perl compatible-regular-expressions)
>   library for pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

Switch to MariaDB. As of 10.0.5 MariaDB supports PCRE https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/

Answer (score 0):

MariaDb and PHP do not implement PCRE exactly the same way:

- no delimiters in MariaDB
- options are given at the beginning this way (?options)

I implemented it there https://github.com/jclaveau/php-logical-filter/blob/master/src/Rule/RegexpRule.php#L57-L82

```
/**
 * Removes the delimiter and write the options in a MariaDB way.
 *
 * @param  string The pattern written in a PHP PCRE way
 * @return string The pattern in a MariaDB syntax
 *
 * @todo   Find more difference between MariaDB and PHP and handle them.
 * @see    https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/
 */
public static function php2mariadbPCRE($php_regexp)
{
    $delimiter        = substr($php_regexp, 0, 1);
    $quoted_delimiter = preg_quote($delimiter, '#');

    if (!preg_match("#^$quoted_delimiter(.*)$quoted_delimiter([^$quoted_delimiter]*)$#", $php_regexp, $matches)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            "The provided PCRE regular expression (with the delimiter '$delimiter') cannot be parsed: "
            .var_export($php_regexp, true)
        );
    }

    $pattern = $matches[1];
    $options = $matches[2];

    return ($options ? "(?$options)" : '') . $pattern;
}
```

There are probably much more differences to deal with but, at least, this is a start :)

Feel free to notice me here if you find some and want your case to be added and tested: https://github.com/jclaveau/php-logical-filter/issues